# SQl Query with even distribution of samples

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to query SQL to get an even distribution of samples.  For example if one of my fields is a State field... I want to query top 5000 results with (100 from each state)... Or another example, if I have a field that says whether a client is a new client or an existing client, and I want the top 500 results where 250 are new clients and 250 are existing clients.

I am trying to avoid two different queries that I have to manually combine the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `ROW_NUMBER`.  You partition your data on one or more columns, so the row numbering starts from 1 in every partition.  You then select the top x rows and ORDER BY the row number column.

e.g.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StateName ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Sales 
)

SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM cte
ORDER BY RN;
```

Comment: on the surface this does exactly what I need it to do... I'm going to have to do some learning and playing with it, to tweak it to all the joins I have to work in.  But overall this gets me there.